# Replace content_main with when opening a new fragment from navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio, fragment

I have googled this and am yet to find an answer,  I am using the Android Navigation drawer template, I have some fragments that replace each other when clicked from the nav menu, When the app first opens it opens on the Content_Main layout, when I click on one of my fragments it opens but the content from the content_main is still showing, I need that to hide while I use other fragments, also make a home button to allow me to go back to this content from the menu, any help ?

The issue is when I open the app, the Content_main layout comes up, when I slide the nav drawer across and select nav_gallery in the menu the music fragment opens but the content main isnt been replaced.

this is my MainActivity

```
package com.justmikey.justmik;

 import android.media.MediaPlayer;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
 import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
 import android.support.v7.internal.widget.ButtonBarLayout;
 import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
 import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
 import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 import JustMikey.Fragments.MainFragment;
 import JustMikey.Fragments.MusicFragment;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

//create a media player object called mp
MediaPlayer mp;
//declare my buttons play, pause and stop
Button play, pause,stop;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Set the textView scrollMain to scrollable
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scrollMain);
    tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,      R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
     }




@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
     }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
     }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camara) {

   fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new MainFragment()).commit();


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new MusicFragment()).commit();


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
 }
```

this is that content_main

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="355dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/jmmain"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/content_frame" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="274dp"
        android:text="hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello  hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello "
        android:id="@+id/scrollMain"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"></ScrollView>


</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my MusicFragmant

```
package JustMikey.Fragments;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.graphics.LightingColorFilter;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.justmikey.justmik.R;

 /**
  *     Created by James on 24/02/2016.
  */
public class MusicFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

//create a media player object called mp
MediaPlayer mp;
//declare my buttons play, pause and stop
Button play, pause,stop;




@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle  savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentmusic, container,  false);


    //call my button views in by using the ID tag
    play = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.play);
    pause = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pause);
    stop = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.stop);

    //set an onClickListener to make my buttons clickable
    play.setOnClickListener(this);
    pause.setOnClickListener(this);
    stop.setOnClickListener(this);

    //Change the colour of the pause button for a nice design effect
    pause.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0x00000000,  0xFFAA0000));
    //return the view
    return rootView;
}
// onClick Method for the play, pause and stop buttons
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.play : if(mp == null) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.holdmytong);
        }
            mp.start();
            break;
        case R.id.pause : mp.pause();break;

        case R.id.stop : mp.stop();mp = null;break;
    }

    }



}
```

The fragment_music layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:src="@drawable/jmholdmy"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="74dp"
    android:id="@+id/pause"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/play"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/play"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/play"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/pausebtnimg" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="113dp"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:id="@+id/stop"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/play"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pause"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/pause"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/stopbtnimg" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="114dp"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:id="@+id/play"
    android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/playbtnimg" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="258dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
    android:text="Taking from our debut EP Hold my tongue was our first released song, it won play at the Picnic competition which brought Just Mikey to the stage at the largest festivil in Europe Electric Picnic, This is the first of many to come so enjoy.  " />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="314dp"
    android:layout_height="156dp"
    android:text="Buy Track: https://www.facebook.com/search/top/?q=just%20mikey%20google%20play"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:backgroundTint="#000000"
    android:backgroundTintMode="screen" />
```

Answer (score 0):

An `AppCompatActivity` should be using a `FragmentManager` retrieved via `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Comment: Is that used for the main_activity ? My other fragments are perfectly working I just need to hide the main content when I I call there Id, how would one do this?

Comment: I don't know what `main_activity` or `content_main` is. There is no mention of it in your code. I assumed that it was a separate fragment and just using `replace` on your fragment transition should replace it.

Comment: I have updated my question if it makes it easier to understand.

Comment: First, change to the support library implementations of `FragmentManager` and `Fragment` and see if that resolves your issue. If not, you should create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to clearly show your problem in a way that is easy to recreate.

Answer (score 0):

Its too late to answer but I'm answering just in case if someone else stumbles upon this question..

To show the `fragment_music` layout without `content_main` behind it, you need to set the background of the `Relative Layout` of your `fragment_music` layout to `white`(or anything you want) that way the `content_main` will hide and your `fragment_layout` will be all that you want to see..